# NodeJS Как записать в Buffer полученные данные из busboy?

Tags: javascript, node.js, файлы, fileupload, filestream

Добрый вечер.

Использую для получения данных(картинки) busboy.

Получаю данные так:

```
var buffer = Buffer.allocUnsafe(filesize);
req.recvSize = 0;  
 file.on('data', function (data) {
            buffer.write(data,req.recvSize,data.length);
            req.recvSize += data.length;
 });
```

На выходе такая вот ошибка:

```
buffer.js:761
return this.utf8Write(string, offset, length);
^

TypeError: Argument must be a string
at TypeError (native)
at Buffer.write (buffer.js:761:21)
```

Вариант с concat мне не подходит, так как я изначально знаю размер файла и далее мне не нужны лишние действия(из-за этого и решил сразу писать в буффер).

copy тоже не особо хочется использовать, так как все же write записывает данные на прямую, без лишнего копирования(если вы готовы оспорить это, то буду рад почитать ваше мнение в комментариях)

Как можно решить такую ошибку или как правильнее будет принимать данные?

Comment: Я не очень знаком с *busboy*, но судя по ошибке - у вас аргумент `data` не типа `string`, в обработчике события `file.on`. А должен быть типа `string`.

Comment: надо смотреть что за data и откуда она берётся, если там точно валидная строка то можно написать так : buffer.write(data.toString(),req.recvSize,data.length);

Answer (score 1):

Не очень понятно по куску кода, что такое `file`. Скорее всего это ваш `request` к серверу. Проверьте, не указали ли вы где-то кодировку. Что-то типа `res.setEncoding('utf8')` В этом случае как раз на событие data у вас придёт объект типа строка, а не Buffer.

Но в целом, вы особо не выигрываете, относительно concat массива буферов `Buffer.concat(buffers)`. Потому что в data событие вам уже приходит готовый выделенный объект Buffer, и разницы, когда его копировать - изначально, или в самом конце не очень много. К тому же, несмотря на заявленную длину файла вам фактически может и не приехать столько данных (порвётся соединение, сервер передумает), а вы уже выделили память подо всё это.

Кстати, внутри Buffer.concat использует `copy`, для копирования данных, а не `write`